# Allow more than one answer to be accepted

Tags: feature-request, accepted-answer

Sometimes, after a few days, there are two or three good answers to a question, or answers which are very much like each other. It can be hard to choose which to accept. I think that after two days, you should be able to accept up to three answers, and the 15 points should be divided between the three answerers.

(Maybe this could be limited to only accepting answers you have upvoted yourself.)