# Some questions deserve more than one accepted answer

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Accept Multiple Answers or Split Bounty among Several Users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2786/accept-multiple-answers-or-split-bounty-among-several-users)
>   [Why Isn’t There a Way to Consolidate Answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7008/why-isnt-there-a-way-to-consolidate-answers)

I think a question can have more than one accepted answer.

Question exampled: what are the advantages of WPF?

Someone posts 3 advantages and another posts another 3 advantages and all 6 are good points.

Which one are you going to choose? Choose the first? Choosing one implies the other answer wasn't good or wasn't good enough which isn't the case.

Comment: To the question, link it!

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17257/allow-more-then-one-answer-to-be-accepted

Comment: It will lead you here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6914/woudnt-it-make-sense-to-have-more-than-one-answer-acceptable

Comment: And here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2786/accept-multiple-answers-or-split-bounty-among-several-users

Comment: Dupes all the way down!

Comment: I thought was a dupe too at first. I was right.

Answer (score 0):

That is one use of a community wiki to handle things that do not have a set defined answer. Or someone needs to combine/edit the good answers into one nice one if the parties involved play nicely and proper credit is given. Got a link to the question... in question?