# Select two answers?

Tags: feature-request, reputation, answers

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Woudn't it make sense to have more than one answer acceptable?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6914/woudnt-it-make-sense-to-have-more-than-one-answer-acceptable)
>   [Allow more than one answer to be accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17257/allow-more-than-one-answer-to-be-accepted)

Sometimes there are two completely correct answers given by two users which are not at all overlapping. I would like to be able to select a "secondary" answer. Both answerers should get the rep and future users should see that the other answers.

The reason why I am reposting is because the other posts deal specifically with StackOverflow. I am talking about stackexchange in general. When you are dealing with programming, answers are either right or wrong.

> How do you log an error in Objective-C? 
>   Answer: NSLog(@"Error");

When dealing with things like cooking, philosophy and religion, for example, things get a little more interesting.

> What do you season scrambled eggs with?
>
> Answer: Salt
>
> Answer: Pepper

Both answers are correct, but they can't be merged.

Comment: Could you provide an example?

Comment: @Jon: In this case it is the same user with two answers. It should be merged... But imagine it was two different users and this example will fit for this case: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4038978/340760

Comment: How about instantiating an array? There are multiple ways to do it. Even though there may be a more "elegant" way, there are multiple ways to do so.

Comment: @BrunoLM - Actually, I was talking about where there are two users who offer alternative answers which are correct.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Woudn't it make sense to have more than one answer acceptable?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6914/woudnt-it-make-sense-to-have-more-than-one-answer-acceptable) and [Allow more then one answer to be accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17257/allow-more-then-one-answer-to-be-accepted).