# What if two answer are correct on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, reputation, answers

As a matter of justice, should SO not come with algorithm which also gives additional points to each of them having correct answers?

Comment: No, it depends on OP to select the correct answer, as some users tend to repfarm by copying the answers above, doesn't mean they should get a point because they answered correct, and FYI, SO cannot write an algorithm that which answer is correct

Comment: if two(or more) answers are correct and solve my problem, I always upvote all of them and accept the first answer

Comment: Also: [Allow more than one answer to be accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17257)

Comment: Votes mean "correct", *acceptance* means "this is the solution I used".

Answer (score 7):

That is what upvotes are for.

Comment: Upvote would be given to all the correct questions.

Comment: @user174889 Exactly. Upvote all the correct answers, and accept the answer that solved the problem.

Comment: @user000001 upvote _ALL_ the answers!

Comment: Upvoted this because... IS THE ONLY ANSWER! MUAHHAHAHA!

Comment: @ColeJohnson *ALL* answers? Even [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1598790/828193)?

Comment: @user000001 [YES](http://m.quickmeme.com/meme/3vnk17/)

Comment: This seems very democratic which doesn't always help the situation, if your answer is different to another and helps all the same, it may come across as being overly efficient