# Multiple Accept Answer for Subjective Questions

Tags: feature-request, accepted-answer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Woudn’t it make sense to have more than one answer acceptable?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6914/woudnt-it-make-sense-to-have-more-than-one-answer-acceptable)

Need to have a feature where user can accept answers for multiple questions. This will be useful in subjective questions where there is no one correct answers.

Comment: Dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6914/woudnt-it-make-sense-to-have-more-than-one-answer-acceptable

Comment: Why do you want to turn it into a discussion board?

Answer (score 4):

Rather than have multiple, wouldn't it be better to have NONE?  I mean, how can a subjective question even have an "ANSWER"?

Comment: I could see rare instances (like on the ASP.NET forums) where you can mark more than one post as an answer if they both provided important information, but it does not translate as well here. Also you are right...something which is more discussion shouldn't have an accepted answer anyway.

Answer (score 3):

If it's truly subjective and doesn't have a right answer, then it should have 0 accepted answers.