# Accepting two or more Answers on a single question

Tags: feature-request, accepted-answer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Woudn’t it make sense to have more than one answer acceptable?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6914/woudnt-it-make-sense-to-have-more-than-one-answer-acceptable)

Assume that you post a question which actually asks two questions. If one user answers half, and another user answers the other half, then you may want to accept both answers. But you can't.

I'm suggesting a feature to allow users to accept two or more answers for their questions.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13396/which-answer-do-i-accept-if-i-have-multiple-correct-answers

Comment: Why not post a link to the question in question so we can see what you're talking about? I don't see any situation where this would be useful, so I'd like to see what makes you think it would be.

Comment: The requisite dupe list: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2786/, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20063/, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18512/, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6914/ ... I'm voting to close based on 6914, myself.

Comment: @Cigars - One day I'll have enough navel-gazing reputation to vote to close too...

Comment: @ChangeIsCool: I hate to say it, but the navel gazing is more fun than the real sites these days. I've taken to pretty much just editing on SO. Although I did gain more rep today on SF than I had in the past several months. (Like, since beta.)

Comment: Back @Cigars - To an extent, I agree. I enjoy the discussions that go on here, because they aren't allowed on SO. I also enjoy watching people abbreviate my new name.

Answer (score 20):

I'll make a counter-suggestion: Ask your two questions in two questions.

Comment: +2 if I could. Anything else is abusing the design of SO.

Comment: But @mmyers if the questions are similar and are very related. If I post two questions people will say to post in the first.

Comment: @Nathan: Not in my experience - Usually it's obvious that requirements changed.  Providing a link to the previous question saves typing too..

Comment: How related are we talking? If they're that close, I can't imagine that someone would be able to answer one part but not the other.

Comment: If one person can answer one question, and another person can answer the other, then there's two distinct questions there, and they should be asked separately.

Comment: +infinity if I could.