# Which answer do I accept when there is one to each part of my question?

Tags: support, accepted-answer, specific-question

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Woudn't it make sense to have more than one answer acceptable?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6914/woudnt-it-make-sense-to-have-more-than-one-answer-acceptable)
>   [Accepting two or more Answers on a single question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29505/accepting-two-or-more-answers-on-a-single-question)

I have [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9489766/unordered-list-on-two-columns-easiest-way-to-do-it/9490039), where I asked an issue with 2 requests and 2 users answered each of them. I did upvote both of them, but I can only accept one.

**What should I do in this case?**

I feel like this is a fairly common situation, where there are 2 answers that fit or are eligible to be accepted, but you can only accept one. This implicitly neglects the other, and I don't think that's right. How can you compensate the effort of the neglected one?

Comment: It's a bit late now, but you should avoid asking multiple questions in a single post

Comment: Actually because it is about the same issue I am trying not to spam or address questions that relate very much because this could lead to the deletion of one of them if people feel that they are too much related and could be answered in the same topic (which is the case that I adopted). This could also lead to a question of rules and respecting them :)

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29505/accepting-two-or-more-answers-on-a-single-question

Comment: Just accept the [jquery answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9490013/212940), they are always right.

Comment: Also, in response to *"How can you compensate the effort of the neglected one?"* you can always add a bounty and award it to the other answer.

Comment: If I've answered it, you should always accept my answer! (^_^) ... Otherwise, accept the jQuery answer, the answer that favors normalized data, and/or the answer that minimizes regex.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should decide, which is better for **you** and which helped **you** the most. In this case, I'd accept [SKS's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9490037/1044146), because it's more detailed and **maybe** more helpful than the other one, but it's just my subjective opinion.

This situation happened because you asked two questions in one post, which is discouraged, you have had to create two posts instead of one. Do it next time, you'll have it all easier!

Answer (score 3):

First place: accept the best answer for your problem
If there are more then one, I pick the one that was fastest/first.

Answer (score 2):

I normally go for the answer that shows more effort creating and displays good formatting and answering practices.

If necessary drop a comment on the second one thanking and explaining that the posted answer also helped solve part of the issue.

In the end it is up to you but normally if you need to make that kind of decisions that only means that the question you asked should be split in to 2 separate ones, which is from start, not a good idea.