# Mark multiple answers as correct

Tags: feature-request, accepted-answer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Woudn't it make sense to have more than one answer acceptable?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6914/woudnt-it-make-sense-to-have-more-than-one-answer-acceptable)

I've posted a question here a few days ago ([Shuffle list with some conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5899274/shuffle-list-with-some-conditions))
and I've received a lot of help from 2 users, and I feel that both had an enormous contribution to my problem. So I feel if I mark one of them as correct, I am despising the effort that the other one had toward my problem.

I would like to mark both answers as correct or at least compensate the one that doesn't get his answer as correct so his effort is not despised.

Comment: You mean _answers_.

Comment: This has been asked and answered multiple times. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6914/woudnt-it-make-sense-to-have-more-than-one-answer-acceptable

Comment: @SLaks: Yes I do!

Comment: @hammar: I didn't know of meta, searched for one on stackoverflow, please delete this one if needed!

Comment: its called voting.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot accept multiple answers.

You should accept one and vote for the other (or for both).

If you really want to express gratitude, you can offer a bounty.

Comment: but then again, only the correct gets all bounty, if , at least bounty can be divided into several answers, there the problem would be solved!

Comment: @Mg01 - you can award multiple bounties now.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot accept more than 1 (one) answer.

If you have [sufficient reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges), you can [upvote](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-up) as many helpful answers as you want. Currently this requires 15 rep.

Comment: I Do Know I cannot accept more than one, that is why I'm posting this!

Comment: Hence, the second sentence.