# Why stackoverflow can have one and only one answer?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, questions, accepted-answer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Accept Multiple Answers or Split Bounty among Several Users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2786/accept-multiple-answers-or-split-bounty-among-several-users)

I see many answers to the same question mention or quote other people's answers, and i think they are both the right answer to the question or they answer the question together, but people can accept one and only one as the right answer.

Why?

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6914/woudnt-it-make-sense-to-have-more-than-one-answer-acceptable and the many questions that it links to.

Comment: Because "The accepted answer is the answer the question owner thought best met their needs."

Comment: Because the gathering is coming. Obviously.

Comment: please add the word "accepted" in the title

Answer (score 1):

If you and another user post an answer, and you find that your answers are very similar, the key to success is to make your answer stand out from the crowd.

- Look at the question that's being asked. Ask yourself if you've answered every point in the question. If not, make an edit to cover missing points.
- Is there more you could do to explain the answer so that it would make sense to future visitors? Not everyone is at the same technical level, and your answer should target future visitors, not just the asker. If you think you can make your answer clearer to more people, consider editing your answer to improve it.
- Are there any references you could cite? Could you show a code example to make your answer clearer? If so, edit your answer to include this information.
- Did anyone leave any comments on your answer that are relevant? If so, move that information into the answer. Feel free to quote the user if you want. Remember, comments are second class citizens, so moving information into your answer ensures it will last for years to come.
- Finally, edit your answer to correct grammatical mistakes and formatting. Make sure you use whitespace to make your answer readable.

Not only will these tips help your answer stand out an possibly get accepted, but other visitors will more likely upvote your post instead. Good luck!