# Shall I accept an answer that answers part of my question?

Tags: discussion, answers, accepted-answer

So I bet you all met into a scenario, where someone wrote a good, detailed answer which answers part (or most, or the core) of your question. Then should you mark it as accepted? Or should you just don't accept it immediately, and wait if he updates the question or other better answers are written. As a question which's marked with an accepted answer might make people don't click into it.

Comment: The fact that you can't/aren't supposed to accept partial answers is intentional, to discourage users from posting partial answers. See [Adding a way to mark answer as "partially accepted"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/308860/adding-a-way-to-mark-answer-as-partially-accepted)

Comment: You should comment on the answer, explaining that it only partially fulfills your request, and ask for it to be edited to fully answer the question.

Comment: @SonictheWizardWerehog where does it say you aren't supposed to accept partial answers and since when is it discouraged to post partial answers? Please don't link me to that answer of yours on that feature request. Any other link form MSE that backs that statement of you will do.

Comment: @rene See here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6914/wouldnt-it-make-sense-to-have-more-than-one-answer-acceptable?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @SonictheWizardWerehog that is about multiple accepted answers. Not what you claim.

Comment: @rene Look at the questions closed as duplicates of that question.

Comment: None of those apply here IMO @SonictheWizardWerehog

Comment: I don't understand how a discussion question can be closed as a duplicate of a feature request for having two accept votes per question. The answer on the duplicate lacks any guidance how to deal with situation the OP describes: A single answer that doesn't fully address their question. I give you a dupe exists, the one currently selected nor the one provided in the comments (or the ones linked from there) apply. Re-opening.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you accept as an answer is up to you. It is your accept vote and it only indicates that the specific answer helped you most. By that definition the answer doesn't strictly need to answer all of what you asked in your question. No one else can or should decide for you if an answer helped you.

But it does help future visitors if your question has complete answers that address all aspects of your question without your question itself being too broad.

Before you accept an partial answer consider and verify the following concerns:

- Did the user who provided an answer overlooked something important? A comment can help to get that confirmation
- Is your question maybe to blame for the kind of answers you got? Inform the participants and foremost edit your question (either improve or remove unclear parts) so future visitors will not have the same confusion
- Is your question focused enough on a single topic? If questions lack focus / are a bit broad, answerers might stick to the bits they can manage to write an answer for in under an hour or so.
- Is the part that wasn't addressed maybe a good fit for a follow up question? In that case ask a new question and make sure to link back to your now answered question.
- Did you wait long enough? Some high traffic sites have highly effective users that start out their answer with a few reasonable text-blurbs (some call this the Fastest Gun In The West) and then expand/revisit their answer in the next hours/days.

If none of the above apply and you're happy enough that you got a substantial part answered, accept the answer. There is no obligation to accept an answer. If you feel the question is valid as it stands and none of the answers address the topic at hand to your liking, do **not** cast an accept vote. Consider casting an up vote if you found an (partial) answer useful.