# Allow answers to be merged

Tags: feature-request, answers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Why Isn’t There a Way to Consolidate Answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7008/why-isnt-there-a-way-to-consolidate-answers)

Don't know if this has been asked already, but what about allowing to users to merge their answers.

I often see the following:  User A gives a good answer, and User B, gives a good answer.  The two together, make the accepted solution.  So maybe a mechanism to combine the two.

With this suggestion, I make no recommendation how this might work, because I can't think of a good way :-P  Maybe allowing the person who posted the question to accept two answers might be better, splitting the credit between the two people.

Comment: I sort of like this idea, but I also can't think of how to implement this properly if it was to be.

Answer (score 2):

The OP can edit one of the two and append the other into that... I've done it in the past

Answer (score 1):

Similar things have been requested in the past (being able to [accept multiple answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2786/accept-multiple-answers-or-split-bounty-among-several-users) is the more common suggestion, i think). The big problem becomes, how do you divvy up the credit? For all its wiki-like features, SO leans heavily on individual contribution and associated rewards (rep, badges).

That said, it's easily accomplished manually - either by editing one answer to include the other ([as Juan Manuel suggests](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26825/nutty-feature-request-answer-merge/26826#26826)), or posting a new answer combining the two existing answers.

#### See also: [Why Isn’t There a Way to Consolidate Answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7008/why-isnt-there-a-way-to-consolidate-answers)