# How to mark multiple right answers

Tags: support, answers, accepted-answer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why Isn’t There a Way to Consolidate Answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7008/why-isnt-there-a-way-to-consolidate-answers)

Suppose a question receives more than one answer, out of which I find that two that each address exactly 50% of the question. In my view, both should be marked answers to the question. Is there a way to mark them thus?

Comment: Also see the fas here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/how-does-stackoverflow-work-the-official-faq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write your own answer using contents of other answers and accept it as the right answer.

Answer (score -1):

No. The only thing that you could do is to give each an upvote.