# bounties. what if nobody satisfies my question?

Tags: feature-request, bounties

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Accept Multiple Answers or Split Bounty among Several Users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2786/accept-multiple-answers-or-split-bounty-among-several-users)

Every time I started a bounty question, I normally ended up having answers that did not really solve my problem. However, I got some interesting ideas in any case, just I didn't get the "perfect answer" I was hoping for. When the bounty is close to expire, I am torn.
The reason why I am torn is that I cannot really give the bounty to anyone in specific. None of the answers really satisfy my question, and choosing one or another really makes no difference. I'm not satisfied anyway of the final answers, although I got the chance to obtain additional information that may be in some case useful for better understanding, and clearly demonstrate the skills and professional development of those who answered.

I'd like to propose a mechanism to solve this situation: propose an additional resolution button allowing to divide the bounty among all answers, in proper proportion to their total votes.

Comment: An unsatisfactorily-answered question is an unanswered question. Multiple-accepted-answers does nothing to mitigate this. If one or more answers helped you find the final solution, then edit one of them to reflect it.