# accept two answers

Tags: feature-request, accepted-answer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Accept Multiple Answers or Split Bounty among Several Users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2786/accept-multiple-answers-or-split-bounty-among-several-users)

Can I have a feature in which I divide my "acceptance coin"
into parts totaling 100%  and  award parts to >1 answers.

In reality, two answers to my question (*1) give equal
amounts of vital information, different pieces of information, from two different aspects.
I wish to "accept both, at 50% of my accept coin ech each".

Taken together, they give complete answer.
Separately, neither answer is complete.
This is important point.
It is not justified to accept one without accepting the other. Deadlock ?

How can I do it ? (*1 )(*2)

(*1) [cross-platform printing of 64-bit integers with printf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6299083/cross-platform-printing-of-64-bit-integers-with-printf)
(*2) one answer by DigitalRoss, another from Random832

Comment: 15 is not divisible by 2 (assuming we still want integer scores)

Comment: ok, 7+8 is fine

Comment: Ah, but now which to give the 7 and which the 8? Clearly you should accept 1 3 5 or 15 answers.

Comment: @Peng, I have no problem to decide which one gets 7 and which 8.

Answer (score 2):

You could vote each answer up, then make a new composite answer yourself (referencing their answers, of course) that brings in the right elements from each and accept that as the answer. This way you give each of them 10 points and provide a cleaner single answer for posterity.

Comment: I am afraid, if I start doing this, answerers will notice my behaviour and say "he is stealing our answers", no ?

Comment: if you give them credit in your answer, and you are not actually just repeating what they say then it's fine...