# Can I accept two answers given for my question?

Tags: discussion, answers, accepted-answer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Accept Multiple Answers or Split Bounty among Several Users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2786/accept-multiple-answers-or-split-bounty-among-several-users)

I asked a file copying issue on Stack Overflow, and I got two answers that are both correct. Can I accept both the answers? Please help me, I don't know more about accepting answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can not accept both answers. You have to accept only one but you can upvote both (or one) of them. In my opinion, you should accept the answer which is detailed and to the point but it is completely up to you which answer to accept.

Comment: That's a guidance, no rule. Just accept the answer which is most comfortable, for whatever reason.