# Answer Bounty Question, But Split Bounty

Tags: discussion, feature-request, bounties

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Accept Multiple Answers or Split Bounty among Several Users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2786/accept-multiple-answers-or-split-bounty-among-several-users)

I think I may be close to answering my own question that I set a bounty to a couple of days ago. There have been three different answers, two of which really helped lead me in the right direction.

I wanted to know if there was a way to be able to split the bounty amongst the three people in a way that was fair, including everyone for contributing and more for the answers that helped lead me in the right direction?

Comment: @JeremyBanks when I was searching I didn't find someone had posted regarding that issue and realize why the bounty the way it is. Definitely will use bounties still.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible. A bounty may only be awarded to a single user.

The only way to give reputation to a second user you would be by adding a second bounty. Unfortunately, this [would also need to be at least twice as large as your first bounty](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/105639/134300).