# How can I assign a bounty and the "accepted answer" checkmark to more than two equally good answers?

Tags: discussion, reputation, answers, bounties, accepted-answer

I posted a question and added a 100 point bounty.

I got (so far) three equally great answers. Each of the answers approached the problem from a different angle. All three answers are independent. All three answers are equally useful.

So far, I upvoted each answer, obviously.

What are some ways I can distribute the bounty points and the "accepted answer" checkmark? Ideally, each of the three persons who provided the great answers should get some points.

**I realize that it is impossible to give *equal* extra points to each answer - but *some* extra points should be possible.**

I am aware that I cannot split the bounty on my own, on purpose. And I am aware that I cannot split the accepted answer checkmark. So awarding `(100 + 15) / 3`, or approximately `40` points to each answer is not a realistic option - those are the rules.

I was considering these possibilities:

1. Award arbitrarily one answer the "accepted answer" checkmark, award another answer the 100 point bounty, and thank the third answerer profusely (they will be left with nothing from me except +10 points upvote).
2. **Do the above, and then post a new bounty** (it must be 200 points at least according to the bounty rules). The third answer will get this new, much larger, bounty. So: `+15`, `+100`, and `+200` to each of the answers, correspondingly (in an arbitrary order).

**References:**

- [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/16065/578690) - useful info about bounties.
- [Preventing ActiveRecord migration from making huge changes in db/structure.sql - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77848079/preventing-activerecord-migration-from-making-huge-changes-in-db-structure-sql) - my original post with the 3 answers that I refer to above.

**Update February 1, 2024:**

For this question, I got so far [a great and interesting answer below](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/396381/578690) from [*Shadow Wizard Love Zelda*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/152859/). I plan to try this method next time.

For the current question, I ended up choosing my **Method 2** (above), that is, "accepted answer" checkmark (`+15` points) and `+100` point bounty and `+200` point bounty. This is because the three answers were super helpful, and not at all simple or obvious. Thus, donating my own earned points seemed like the best thing to do in this case.

Comment: See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2786/accept-multiple-answers-or-split-bounty-among-several-users

Comment: @RobertLongson Thank you for the comment and the link. I agree with the accepted answer (by *Shog9*) for the linked Q *in general*: [Accept Multiple Answers or Split Bounty among Several Users - Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/7429/578690). But in my case all 3 answers are different and all are equally valuable. As the comment to your *Shog9*'s answer says: *"To award increased, non-average effort. [...]different research might bring up different sources [...], all of them equally valid. Often there is no final answer, because science is open-ended." – 
user215347*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a fair discussion, and getting three good answers is a big bonus in general so first of all, well done!

Having said that, sadly, currently there's no way you can achieve what you want, i.e. give same amount of rep to all three answers with bounties. *Not by yourself*.

However, if those answers are really good, here is what I would have done:

- Give the bounty to one of the answers, let's call it answer A.
- Share answers B and C in chat, explain why you think they're good .
- Wait for some feedback, and if people agree, and have high rep, kindly encourage them to award those answers as well with a bounty.
- **DO NOT** directly ask "plz give bounty!!1!".
- **DO NOT** flood, i.e. ask once, and hopefully you'll get feedback in chat.

Comment: I like this method, thank you! What do you think about my question's potential method, option 2 (accept answer checkbox for #1, 100 pt bounty for #2, 200 pt bounty for #3)? I don't mind spending extra 200 points in addition to those 100 points already spent. :)

Comment: @Timur well that would mean uneven points, which might not be "fair" but yeah, no doubt more simple than asking others for help, and better than only the one bounty.

Comment: Thank you very much!  I ended up not using your method this time, but plan to try it next time. See the **Update** at the end of my question.