# Option to Share Reputation Earned from a Bounty

Tags: feature-request, bounties

This question is similar to [Collaborative Answers/Point-Sharing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2445/collaborative-answers-point-sharing) but I'm thinking more specifically about sharing reputation from an awarded bounty, where the person who receives the bounty has the option to share a portion of the bounty with another user(s).

By way of example, I received a bounty for [re-iterating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3513862/android-live-wallpaper-offset-clipping/3544107#3544107) another user's answer. I gave verbal credit and a link to the original answer but I would have shared some of the bounty if I had the option.

**EDIT:** Another example in a new comment to this popular [question about dog paws](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3684484/404469). (It's a new comment, so you will have to expand the comments to see it).

"I so wish I could split the bounty, because there is clearly more than one answer here deserving some; but for the lack of that ability I'll just go with the highest-voted answer"

Comment: Surely if an answer to another question also applies to this question, then this question is a duplicate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you receive a full bounty and want to split it with someone, and it is over 50 bounty, you can always just host your own bounty at whatever lower denomination you wish, and award it to who you wanted to split the bounty with.

You won't be able to split evenly on bounties that end in 50, but at that point, the difference is barely more than 2 upvotes. If someone is inspiring you enough to *want* to split a bounty, then it should not be difficult to find 2 answers that are good enough to earn upvotes.

Comment: Good suggestion.

Comment: Accepting this as the best answer so far, a good work-around. ;)