# How can I acknowledge, thank, or otherwise approve of an edit?

Tags: feature-request, edits, suggested-edits, etiquette, thanks

Sometimes I get an edit that greatly improves a question or answer I have submitted.  I'd like to acknowledge an edit like this, so that readers can know that the revision was approved of by the OP (me!).

I was thinking of comments on edit, or a checkbox noting that OP vouches for the edit.  Sometimes I would like to add a comment to the question or answer, but those don't make a lot of sense in that context.

Any suggestions about the best way to do this?  Consider this a feature request, as it seems useful to know that a particular edit was endorsed/vetted by the OP.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

#### [Pay it forward...](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/101126/165773)

...Memorize the way how your post has been improved and when you see another one that could be edited that way, just do it.

<sub>As someone regularly doing edits like you mention <sup>([1](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/posts/148524/revisions), [2](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/posts/155445/revisions), [3](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/posts/155331/revisions), [4](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/posts/146856/revisions), [5](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/posts/148431/revisions), [6](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/posts/104761/revisions)...)</sup> I would say above is exactly what would make me happy.</sub>

Answer (score 8):

You can actually @-notify users who edit your posts, but you should avoid just saying thanks and use these for explaining things to the editor. A lot of people don't like this type of noise and it will likely be deleted if someone flags it. I've gotten a few "thanks" notifications like this, and they can get annoying if too many people do it in short succession. Ultimately, your approval of the edit is not rolling back. Isn't that good enough?

[Jeff Atwood states:](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17878/thanking-users-who-answered-my-question)

> anyone posting here with the idea that they should be personally thanked for every answer they provide is going to be very disappointed

The same goes for edits. We edit things to improve the community, we don't need to be thanked every time.

Answer (score 6):

Though well-intended, all such expressions are more or less noise that only clutters the page.

If you really want to thank someone, you could think of specifically awarding a bounty on one of their answers, should you consider it particularly good. And if the user still has a "low" reputation ([<2k](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/edit)) they will get rewarded for an accepted edit anyway.

With regards to the OP's approval of an edit, if the OP doesn't like an edit, it will most likely be reversed or rolled back after a while. If that did not happen, we can safely assume they are OK with it. I don't see the need for an explicit notice.

All in all, performing a significant amount of edits myself, I personally just assume people are thankful, especially if their question/answer gets renewed attention and additional upvotes. There is no need to specifically thank me.

Comment: I'm mainly concerned with indicating that the OP has reviewed and approved of the edit.  That's why I'd like to put it on the edit page, and not clutter the main page.  I'll update the question to make this more clear.