# Is there a way to get recognition for improving existing posts?

Tags: discussion, edits

There is the pure philanthropy and feel-good aspect of having contributed, but what I mean is more something reflected in reputation increments. Is/has this been considered before and what is/was the consensus?

<sub>I am thinking about how to recognize edits as improvements, possibly as a 'tick-box' by original poster on acceptance of the modification. Just like reviewers can tick a "Helpful suggestion" box when improving a suggested edit, authors could review their edited posts and check it if the edit added meaningful info.</sub>

Comment: What kind of recognition do you expect? 2 rep per edit with 200 rep cap and a badge on 100th answer edit?

Comment: @FabrícioMatté: thx for responding: I don't know what the current setup is, hence the question; does your comment reflect this, and where would it be documented so I can get clued-up?

Comment: I would approve some recognition as long as it doesn't instigate bad behavior - e.g. badge/reps usually instigate a lot of a unnecessary minuscule grammar/punctuation edits as was often seen on the Proposed Edits queue. +1 for the discussion.

Comment: Also from what I remember, Wiki posts do not give reputation anymore because people would add a couple commas just to leech some reputation. I guess it might be hard to give any recognition more than the aforementioned philanthropy, even though it'd be nice.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté: I agree, problem would be how to recognize edits as improvements, possibly as a 'tick-box' by original poster on acceptance of the modification.

Comment: Nice idea, just like reviewers can tick a "Helpful suggestion" box when improving a suggested edit, authors could review their edited answers/questions and check it if the edit added meaningful info.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté, I will only endorse that if I can have a "This edit is a pile of crap how dare you touch my post, die" button as well. Maybe it could blast the people who approved a crap edit rather than the editor :-). I've had people suggest some [pretty pathetic](http://stackoverflow.com/review-beta/suggested-edits/221746) "improvements" before (this one changes a well lined up parenthesis and makes it appear as though I don't know what SQL is). Of course, this would be massively open to abuse so it'll never happen but a boy can dream :-).

Comment: @Ben: :) ..abuse: on the FOAD-button or the meaningful-checkbox?

Comment: related: [How can I acknowledge, thank, or otherwise approve of an edit?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/142142/165773) _"Sometimes I get an edit that greatly improves a question or answer I have submitted. I'd like to acknowledge an edit like this..."_

Comment: @gnat: "Pay it forward" I think is really the natural (tacit?) basis for SO (and SE) and the rep is just recognition by peers

Comment: I'm not keen on the complaints this would bring to Meta.