# Write a Testimonial

Tags: feature-request

I want to write a testimonial to a guy that answered my question. This will be like a private message and you will only have one a day. This will be great if a guy helped you a lot more than you expected and you want to thank him.

also, I want to write a testimonial to someone that edited my post full of grammar errors...

How can I do this and maybe there can also be a give rep option...

EDIT: I suggest this to give the feature to thanks someone in private and because you are discouraged to "Thank you" in the comment field

Comment: SO is not for writting testimonials. SO is Q/A site not an Social Networking site.

Comment: regarding "testimonial" for editors, see: [How can I acknowledge, thank, or otherwise approve of an edit?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/142158/165773)

Comment: If a user wants private e-mail he has probably put the mail address in his profile. If not, he has not.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want to really do something more you can award bounty to that answer and as @Raynold telling *SO is Q/A site not an Social Networking site* so there is no need of testimonial

you can do something like this

[image]

and this is how you can do this

> [image]

and than write message you want .. but please control feeling while typing

[image]

Answer (score 12):

The system already handles this fairly well:

- You can comment on answers on your question, so you can thank them in their answer
- Upvoting an answer gives the user 10 rep, and accepting the answer gives +15 reputation
- You can post a bounty on your question too, and assign the rep to that user afterwards

I don't see a need for this.

Comment: It is made clear that you must not comment to say thank you...

Comment: Not as a salutation in your question, sure, but I haven't seen anywhere where it's forbidden from thanking a user in the comments of your own question.

Comment: See edited post http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/126184/217125

Comment: So make your "thank you" constructive, such as, "I've been stuck for weeks on this, and `insert code here` is exactly what I was looking for, I wasn't aware of that.  Thank you!"  I don't see why anyone would flag that.  I love flagging things, and I wouldn't even flag that comment.

Comment: @lontgomjr: To be honest, I think that a simple thank you is a good thing. It's really nice to see someone say thank you after the half-hour they've spent on your question. It's one of the human touches on SE that doesn't detract from the primary content, and comments aren't ment for important improve-the-internet content anyway. If good info comes up in comments, it's supposed to be posted into a question or an answer.

Comment: It should also be noted that you can type `@editorUserName` in a comment to a post that someone has edited, and it will alert them of the comment. It just doesn't auto-complete the editor's username like it does other users participating in that post.

Comment: @lontgomjr See the post you yourself linked to.  Thanking someone in comments isn't * forbidden*, it's just not particularly helpful when there are so many other ways in which you can benefit the site so much more.  If it's really *that* important to you to thank someone you can do so, and you won't be stopped, just know that you would be creating more value to the site through other actions.

Comment: Also, it's slightly different when the OP thanks the person who provided the answer to their question, and when some random dude later comments with "Thanks, this solved my problem too".

Comment: Thanks all for comenting and thanks for the awnser... I like a good discussion.. :D