# What are the policies with regards to edits that are submitted to a post, when no action is taken from the OP?

Tags: support, review, edits, suggested-edits

I read [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/142145/152859), and noticed this paragraph:

> With regards to the OP's approval of an edit, if the edit is not approved by the OP it will most likely be reversed or rolled back after a while. If that did not happen, we can safely assume it is approved.

I am wondering whether I should take an action in order to accept and preserve the edits that I like?

I also checked ["How does editing work?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/editing), but I did not find what I was looking for. It was only mentioned that there are certain reviewers who might reverse an edit in special cases.

What is the default / automatic reaction from the "system" if the OP does not take any action? Are the edits going to be reversed automatically or will they remain?
Does it depend on the editors' privileges / reputation?

If I should accept the edits that I like, then how do I do that?

Answer (score 3):

No, you should **not take action** if you approve of an edit made. The edit will show up as the new text of your question for everybody.

The quote says:

> ... If that [rolling back] did not happen, we can safely assume it is approved.

If you **do not approve** of an edit, you can roll it back to any previous revision.

When someone, a user without full editing privileges, suggests an edit, you can unilaterally accept it as OP. You can do this before you get access to the suggested edit review queue. You will be notified in your global inbox when there is a suggested edit being made on your post.

Answer (score 3):

I reworded the answer to make it clearer.

To elaborate more on what happens, the OP is notified of any major edits (changes involving 6+ characters or 2+ characters in code), so most people who are active will quickly go and revert any edits to their posts that they don't like.

Fortunately, in my experience, reverting edits isn't very common. Most of the bad edits I see are [suggested edits that get rejected in review](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/editing). For good edits, most people are reasonable and won't balk when their post is improved.

Answer (score 2):

> What is the default / automatic reaction from the "system" if the OP does not take any action?

None. Nothing happens by default or automatically, and nothing should happen.

You were misled by the answer you read, and to be honest I'm not sure what's the intention behind the sentence you quoted, but I can say for sure, that there is no policy to roll back edits just because OP did not approve them.