# Why was my code edit rejected?

Tags: discussion, rejected-edits, specific-edit

I corrected some wrong code [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2952519) and the edit was rejected almost instantly. Could anyone explain why?

Comment: Not sure why this is down voted, seems like a neutrally worded request for feedback

Comment: @Richard because it's a duplicate. It's pretty pathetic that people downvote duplicate support questions. They help people find the main one if they search for something else. Like they may search for something that is only here, not there. If this didn't exist, then that user would make it a question, and the cycle repeats.

Comment: @ColeJohnson This isn't a duplicate: this was actually an edit to an answer, not a question.

Comment: As stated, this is not a duplicate of that question, though it may be a duplicate of similar issues from 2011 [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96431) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78845), and from 2 months ago [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/192469), or a couple days ago [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200055).

Answer (score 22):

You have edited code in an answer.

Your changes include adding a space character (`function (e)` instead of `function(e)`), which is only a matter of personal coding style, as well as performing a strict equality comparison against a number instead of a non-strict comparison against a string (which are roughly equivalent in Javascript, and also a matter of personal style).

You should refrain from editing code to have it conform to your own coding style. Such edits will be summarily rejected most of the time. That's the answerer's code, not yours: except for obvious typos, leave it as it is.

Comment: Does it matter that the code didn't work before I edited it and did work after I did?

Comment: @kzar, that's only because you fixed the typo in `stopPropagation()`. Your other changes did not make the code any better (or worse, for that matter).

Comment: Well it's not fair to say the comparison correction did not improve the code but I accept the rest of the changes were stylistic. Unfortunately I couldn't submit a change with less than 6 characters difference though so the tweaking was thrust upon me rather.

Comment: You did not have to edit the code and nothing was thrust upon you. I understand your frustration, but until such time as you have enough reputation to be "trusted" by the community to make unreviewed edits I would avoid editing code (for your own sanity, as edits to code in general are suspect especially accepted answers).

Comment: @user7116 I hope most people will understand why not to edit code before they get to be trusted to make unreviewed edits. Except putting code in a code block if it isn't in one yet. But that's hardly editing code in the first place.

Comment: @kzar Yes, it did matter, and I think this edit should have been approved. Correcting something that almost worked, but had a minor mistake, is what edits are all about.

Answer (score 12):

Editing someone's incorrect code is not a good practice. If you think the answer has some issues, you can comment on the answer. If the author don't reply you, you can downvote the answer and add your own answer with valid code. So reviewers mostly reject such edits.

Comment: I was not allowed to comment on his code as I had < 50 karma. (I see that Hugo Dozois - as well as marking this question a duplicate - has gone in and added the comment himself.)

Comment: @kzar If you don't have enough reputation to comment then *earn* that reputation, and then comment.  You aren't permitted to violate the rules simply because you don't have enough reputation to do what you would like to do.

Comment: No I think rather than jump through hoops - on the way to what was already a favour for the next reader - I'll simply not bother with any of this at all.

Comment: @kzar: the hoops are actually a means of including newer users. Previous to these hoops you had 0 means of editing input.

Comment: I thought it was a fair enough edit and well explained. I would have approved it. Had it been the questions code snippet then I'd have rejected.

Comment: Editing someone's mostly-correct code is good practice. Please read the [official editing guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/help/editing) (“When should I edit posts? (…) To correct minor mistakes”). A comment is only appropriate when you know that something is wrong but are unable to correct it: [comments are for unresolved issues](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @Gilles - May be you have misunderstood *"some issues"*. I didn't say I will reject typo correction. But I will probably reject edit of some *minor-looking* mistakes like using `SUM` instead of `COUNT` (for e.g.).

Comment: @hims056 Your example sounds exactly like the kind of minor mistake that should be corrected by an edit.

Comment: What @Gilles said...in the (non-)capacity as an SO ex-mod.