# What can I do when my edit was rejected unjustified

Tags: support, rejected-edits

I suggested [this edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3430873) to an answer after evaluating both the problem and the solution with the right ingredients. I read question, answers, and comments carefully before I suggested the edit, because I wished to be sure not to introduce any consistency errors by editing. I think some of my reviewers didn't spend enough time as to really check this edit.

I don't try to suggest the same edit again. Instead, I commented the suggested edit below the answer.

Is this all I can do? *(besides this meta question)*

Comment: Your edit was good.  I always appreciate it when others find a small error in my answers and correct it.  It's always good to make answers better.

Comment: @LanceRoberts No, the edit was not good. It should have been a comment.

Comment: @Lance Edits should not change the content of an answer. Comments are to alert the OP of potential problems.

Comment: @Emracool, no, it's ok to make simple edits to fix simple errors.  The goal is good answers, and it helps everyone, including the answerer who made the mistake.

Comment: If your answer is broken, then it is a poor answer that does not solve the problem. If someone like Wolf wants to fix it, that **improves the quality of the answer** and should be encouraged. Good users who are able to proofread code are being given the wrong message every single day because reviewers are allergic to the skip button based on some sort deluded concept of ownership. If you don't want your answers edited, don't make mistakes. If you don't like an edit, roll it back. Rejecting it out of pride is anti-collaboration and goes against the SE concept.

Comment: @Lance Well, that argument really doesn't hold water. It helps the answerer more to either change it themself. A comment makes them aware of the answer's potential error. Also, editing answers risks inducing further errors which are _not_ the fault of the answerer.

Comment: @jmac There are two problems with this: First, it's not your answer to edit. You could be unintentionally introducing errors which are not the fault of the answerer. Second, the _same effect_ is achieved by commenting, but without the risk, and with the responsibility of the person whose rep is at stake to begin with.

Comment: @Emracool, there are many times when the answerer doesn't pay attention to the comments and doesn't come back.  Meanwhile many others might be trying to use that answer.  __All edits are risky.__

Comment: @Emra, perhaps you haven't read [our help center on editing](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/editing): *"if you see questions or answers that can be improved, you can edit them. Use edits to fix mistakes, improve formatting, or clarify the meaning of a post."* It is my answer to edit. Along with anyone else in the community who feels the need. The effect is **not** achieved by commenting since comments are second-class citizens and if accurate should be edited in to the post.

Comment: @jmac "_and if accurate_". The community managers have stated (though I can't remember where) that the intent behind "use edits to fix mistakes" is to correct things like single-character typos. Something which significantly changes the function of the answer _in a way which may not be correct_ is not a good edit, even if it _may_ make the answer correct.

Comment: @Emra, if you don't know if it's correct [learn to love that skip button](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/153279/165773) as Shog9 has said. And <2000 rep users cannot make one character edits. At least get your ducks in a line before you start firing.

Comment: @jmac _I_ use the skip button. Most other reviewers do not. Plus, people push single character edits through by changing words around in minor and unnecessary ways.

Comment: My point is that the reviewers probably don't know whether the edit is correct, and aren't in a position to judge it. Yes, _ideally_ they should use the skip button, but _pragmatically_ they don't, so we have to accommodate their existence.

Answer (score 12):

This edit was validly rejected because it changed the directory in the answer. Remember, the answer is the solution provided by a user, and is representative of their work. You can't go and change that, because the answer would no longer represent their solution.

In this case, the reason:

> This edit is incorrect or an attempt to reply to or comment on the existing post.

is somewhat unclear. If you've spotted what you believe is an error in the answer, then a comment is the correct course of action.

---

To clarify: Reviewers should not have to gauge the *accuracy* of an edit. In doing so, this would violate the purpose of reviewing, which is to create *objectively* good answers. While yes, in an ideal world, people would skip over edits whose accuracy they could not gauge, this does not happen (at least on Stack Overflow), and so we must create pragmatic workarounds by disallowing questionable content edits.

The key word here is "questionable": if your edit is obviously correct, such as a small typographical error in an answer (like `bra` instead of `bar`), it is okay to edit. However, if your edit could potentially change the accuracy of an answer, then it will be rejected.

Comment: I think it's worth adding that if your comment is ignored, you can always post a better answer yourself.

Comment: @sash, that is a horrible alternative. So we get two answers, identical content, only one works, and one doesn't, because of a missing bracket? How is the community supposed to evaluate which is right? Momentum will have the first answer which is 99% right get more votes, while the alternative below the fold gets ignored because nobody can tell the difference. Why are you proposing making the correct answer **more difficult** to find?

Comment: @jmac 1. Missing bracket is "correct minor mistakes" and should be an edit. 2. Don't jump between things - either talk about this particular question (major edit), or in generalities. Have you actually read what you wrote? It sounds ridiculous "one works, and one doesn't" "nobody can tell the difference" - isn't it the purpose of SO to post answers and for users to be able to evaluate it themselves? There is a voting system for that. Otherwise let's post one answer and edit it all the time until it is perfect.

Comment: @sash, the purpose of SE, as was stated at its creation, is to make answers easier to find. That is why edits are allowed on other people's content. If I dig up an answer from a year ago that doesn't work as written because they forgot `/bin/Debug` at the end of the example, then are you really advocating I go and post a second answer rather than edit the +20 accepted answer that already exists? That will not achieve the desired results (my answer would be buried, and would likely be flagged and deleted for covering what was already discussed in another answer, which is also discouraged)

Comment: @jmac That's what a comment is for. Serves both as a flag to the OP and future visitors.

Comment: @jmac Don't rant about the purpose of SE. This is meaningless. Read the rules - if you disagree, propose to change them. But don't encourage people to misuse the system because you think it is better.

Comment: @jmac About this particular example. Comment and leave it there. It will not go anywhere - people will read it and get the idea. If the answer is wrong, its score must reflect it. If not, then why changing it? People voted for the original answer, not an edited version which might not work any more.

Comment: This is true, because of the order of reasons I used in the comment. If did better omitting the first. What I learned from this is that the comment-to-edit relation is crucial. Thanks for pointing me on this.

Comment: @Josh Actually, the translation of the question read like an _actual question_. I don't think [it was indicative of spam](http://prntscr.com/26m6ri). Plus, since the user actually deleted their own question, I think they aren't a spambot.

Comment: Your answer and comments are incorrect on multiple counts. Please read the [purpose of comments](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment): “Comments are **temporary** "Post-It" notes”. Correcting a mistake in an answer is not a temporary thing, it does not belong in a comment. Reviewers should definitely gauge the accuracy of edits, it's part of the job. As a reviewer, [if you don't know, skip](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/153279). @sashkello This goes for you too: you are pretending to instruct people on SE's rules when you clearly haven't read them, please do read them.

Comment: @Gilles Please read the discussions below and above. Comments are used for clarification and to correct mistakes. Reviewers should not gauge the accuracy of an edit - this is policy on SO. The "if you don't know, skip" rule is great in theory, but doesn't work on a site like SO where people review because there are reviews to do. The edit rule for "fixing minor errors" is intended to apply to small things like typos, and not anything that changes the functionality of a post.

Comment: @Emracool I have read the discussion. I have also read the rules, and I have a lot of experience reviewing, including back when there was a sore lack of reviewers on SO (which is no longer the case). If you don't know, skip. The fact that some people are doing it wrong is no reason for you to also do it wrong. Comments are not “used for clarification and to correct mistakes”, they [are used](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) to “**request** clarification” and to “Add relevant but **minor or transient** information to a post”.

Answer (score 8):

### Background

This issue comes up very frequently:

[Suggested Edit rejected because reviewers didn't know programming language](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200055)
[Why was my code edit rejected?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/197405)
[Why was my suggested edit rejected repeatedly?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/192469)

### What Do the Rules Say?

#### Posts are Intended to be Collaboratively Edited

> Editing is important for keeping questions and answers clear, relevant, and up-to-date. If you are not comfortable with the idea of your contributions being collaboratively edited by other trusted users, this may not be the site for you.

#### Useful Information in Comments Should be Edited in to the Post

> Edits are expected to be substantial and to leave the post better than
> you found it. Common reasons for edits include:
>
> - To fix grammar and spelling mistakes
> - To clarify the meaning of the post (without changing that meaning)
> - **To include additional information only found in comments**, so all of the information relevant to the post is contained in one place
> - **To correct minor mistakes** or add updates as the post ages
> - To add related resources or hyperlinks

#### Comments are not Permanent

> #### What are comments?
>
> **Comments are temporary "Post-It" notes** left on a question or answer. They can be up-voted (but not down-voted) and flagged, but do not generate reputation. There's no revision history, and when they are deleted they're gone for good.

#### Comments are Not Intended to Correct Mistakes

> #### When shouldn't I comment?
>
> Comments are not recommended for any of the following:
>
> - **Suggesting corrections** that don't fundamentally change the meaning of the post; instead, make or suggest an edit;

### Conclusion

Code edits are often rejected because people are too lazy to properly evaluate whether or not they are correct, and prefer clicking "reject" rather than "skip" if they don't have the inclination to properly review. To get these sorts of edits approved, you need to bend over backwards to make your average reviewer's life as easy as possible:

### Make sure the edit to code is appropriate

I put together a handy [faq-proposed](/questions/tagged/faq-proposed) to cover when to edit/not to edit code:

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200336/when-should-i-make-edits-to-code

### Improve your suggested edit comment

Right now you wrote:

> fixed some minor issues, the default settings produce a Debug version

You can improve this to:

> This will not work because the directory is wrong, so /HelloWorld/ was changed to /HelloWorld/bin/Debug

Or something more descriptive that tells the reviewer, "This is clearly wrong, and this is why" with a glance. Otherwise they will just reject it because it's "safer".

### Wait for 2000 Rep

Because reviewers are so horrible at these sorts of suggested edits, you can just wait until 2000 reputation so you don't have to deal with them when making common-sense improvements.

---

Have faith knowing that you're in the right. Keep fighting the good fight.

Comment: Your answer is spot on.

Comment: I really don't think the solution to this problem is "ignore quorum, since we're right anyway." Carrying the site in multiple directions is not beneficial for anyone, and creates further problems in communication and action.

Comment: @Emra, on my side: Help Center, SO concept, Answer Quality. On your side: Confused Sense of Ownership, Complex workflows to get worse results, encouraging reviewer laziness. I agree that taking the site in two ways is stupid, I just refuse to sacrifice quality for laziness.

Comment: @jmac Help Center disagrees with you; "fixing errors" is intended for minor things like single-character typos, not things which could make the answer incorrect. I don't know what you mean by "SO concept." Answer quality is improved by commenting because the _answerer can edit the answer to reflect its accuracy_. I'm not sacrificing quality for laziness. This is to ensure quality of answers.

Comment: @Emra, you seem to misunderstand the SE concept. The content belongs to the community -- not to you. If I find a mistake in your grammar, I fix it to make the answer better. You are not the guardian of your own content, and you are not allowed to refuse to allow edits because you are wrong and stubborn. That hurts answer quality. The community is smarter than you are. That is why Stack Exchange works. Refusing to let the community touch your answers makes no sense.

Comment: @jmac I'm pretty sure accuracy trumps ownership. When did this become about _me_? I've never rejected an edit from a comment I thought was correct, and I almost always skip past code edits I don't understand. Please stop targeting this at me. We should talk about the _general_ case; if you insist on making this about me, I will leave.

Comment: Totally disagree with this. "to correct minor mistakes or add addendums / updates as the post ages" doesn't mean you need to make a correct answer out of incorrect answer (or in some cases vice versa). Edit reviews shouldn't evaluate the correctness of answers, this is not their purpose. If you disagree propose a change to the SO edit rules rather than calling people who exactly follow the protocol lazy.

Comment: Fixing other people's code = bad. You don't know what the OP intended, and they are not informed about the edit in an obvious way for quality control. Code corrections are what comments are there for.

Comment: This has been gone over already in the linked post. To make an absurdly brainless example, if someone means to type `SELECT foo JOIN bar` but accidentally writes `SLEECT foo JONI bar` then fixing it is not 'evaluating the correctness of answers' but along the lines of correcting a typo in the intended answer. If the answer doesn't work as written, why would we leave it as is? That strikes me as just about the most counter-productive stance to take when trying to help people get proper answers.

Comment: @jmac Your example should be an edit because typos are on the list. But if someone types `SELECT foo LEFT JOIN bar`, you shouldn't change it because it will create a different answer from an existing one.

Comment: Neither of your arguments have anything to do with the original question where content of the answer has been significantly altered with additional code which hasn't been there.

Comment: @sashkello, so why are you saying that `/HelloWorld/` to `/HelloWorld/bin/Debug` is a different answer entirely? Have you tested both? Does the first work just fine, and the second indicate something entirely different? You are seemingly suggesting that this is some radical change to the code different from `SELECT` vs. `SLEECT`, but if a reasonable user versed in that field (as Wolf would seem to be) thinks it is a good change, what is your justification for invalidating his expertise exactly?

Comment: @probablyPekka [Useful comments should be edited in to the post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200055#200070). So I'm a bit confused as to why you want me to make a comment on incorrect code so that someone else can edit it in, rather than just using the tools available to do it directly.

Comment: @jmac 1. I don't have to test it. I didn't ask that question and not interested in it. So the reviewers shouldn't verify the correctness of the answers. If a change looks major, it should be rejected. Forgetting /bin/Debug is obviously not a typo and OP intended HelloWolrd and not HelloWorld/bin/Debug. 2. Let people judge the correctness by voting, that's the only instrument for this. Reviewers never ever should do it.

Comment: @sash, if you are going to advocate that the edit rejection was legitimate, then I would sure hope you'd actually make sure it was. Saying, *"It looks major"* does not make it major. Sometimes something that looks major is actually minor and common sense, and was likely just an omission because code was written directly in the box without testing it first. If someone forgets to include a required library in their sample code, or forgets to declare a variable as the proper type, then adding that should be encouraged even if it *looks* major to make the answer actually work as intended.

Comment: @sash, I absolutely refuse to concede that any code posted as an answer is intended to not work properly as written without something written to explain that it is pseudo-code or not tested. And if someone turns that pseudo-code or non-working code in to something that works as written, no matter how major it *looks* it should be a part of the answer. Our goal is provide reliable answers that are easy to find, not to prevent people from improving things because of how they *look*.

Comment: @jmac You are absolutely refusing to concede a point nobody is trying to make. You are misconstruing the arguments you're responding to a la straw man, and responding as if they said something similar to what they said but which they did not say.

Comment: @Jonathan, what exactly am I misconstruing here?

Comment: @jmac 1. So, now you are saying that basically you can post your own answers by editing someone else's answer no matter how much you should change. Great. 2. There are two lines of code in the answer. Significantly changing one of them is major. Full-stop. 3. I repeat it again in case you missed it: correctness of the answer should be judged by the voting system only and nothing else.

Comment: @sash, I have written [a large explanation open to community editing explaining exactly what I believe that rules on editing code for users under <2k should be](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200336/when-should-i-make-edits-to-code). I have also written [an answer explaining exactly why the alternatives proposed here do not correspond with the site rules](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/200070/209637). My stance on this is crystal clear -- productive edits that make better answers should be encouraged because that is what the rules say edits are for.

Comment: @jmac 4. Every new comment of yours you are introducing new examples, and every time there is a clear answer in "help". First it was a typo, now we've come to changing pseudo-code to a proper code. In between these things there is a border separating major edit from minor, it is flimsy, yes, but it is there.

Comment: @jmac Nobody is arguing someone deliberately and consciously wrote broken code.

Comment: @jmac Your large explanation says under "Answers": "**Don't** ... Change the code logic or functionality - even if you think you're correcting it" (this Don't was there in your original version, though I added the "even if you think you're correcting it" myself afterwards)

Comment: @jmac "productive edits that make better answers should be encouraged because that is what the rules say edits are for." Rules also clearly say in which cases the edit should be done and the extent of the changes. Your statement again claims that you can change whatever to whatever because you think it is better.

Comment: @Jonathan, yes, for instance, adding error handling when none existed, or changing `for` loops to `while` loops to improve performance. If the code does the same thing, in the same order, but works one way and doesn't work the other, then it isn't changing code logic or functionality.

Comment: @jmac Well, clearly `cd`'ing to a different directory (not even mentioned in an original answer) will change the code functionality.

Comment: @jmac Yes it is. Making it work differently (including making it _work_, when the not-working is not just due to a typo) is changing its functionality.

Comment: "works one way and doesn't work the other, then it isn't changing code logic or functionality" - what??? One code is FUNCTIONING and another DON'T. I'm refusing to continue this ridiculous thread...

Comment: @Jonathan, so you are advocating leaving broken code broken in an answer. For what purpose? Who does that help? Does the answer work as-is? If not, why would you advocate leaving a broken answer that can be fixed with the addition of 10 characters?

Comment: Let's try and wrap up the discussion. This argument is spiraling into a long, convoluted string of comments without a solid foundation or purpose. Also, I think it's far past the point of constructiveness; it's sort of going in circles at this point.

Comment: @jmac Yes, I am advocating not changing the functionality of code one _thinks_ is broken in order to perform what they _think_ is a fix, even if one is _absolutely certain_ that what they think is the case. There are better ways to deal with that situation. If you would like the answers to your questions, I suggest you read through the comments above. I agree with Emracool that we should wrap this up, so in the spirit of that, poke me in the Meta tavern if you have anything further.

Comment: Two parting comments. [The rules are principles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:The_rules_are_principles). Our goal is to get high quality answers. Editing helps. That's why it's encouraged on other people's answers (see the about page). [If the rules truly prevent you from improving the encyclopedia, ignore them](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Ignore_all_rules). At the end of the day, broken code helps nobody, and if people want to fix broken answers they should be encouraged, not downvoted on meta for bringing it up.

Comment: @jmac Thanks for your answer. I think my commenting style needs some improvement. In this special case began I begun with the minor edits and then got deeper into the stuff. So the more important part of the change became only the second in the comment.